# Seaborn violin plot over time given numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, seaborn, violin-plot

I have a distribution that changes over time for which I would like to plot a violin plot for each time step side-by-side using seaborn. My initial attempt failed as `violinplot` cannot handle a `np.ndarray` for the `y` argument:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

time = np.arange(0, 10)
samples = np.random.randn(10, 200)

ax = sns.violinplot(x=time, y=samples)  # Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

The seaborn [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) has an example for a vertical violinplot grouped by a categorical variable. However, it uses a DataFrame in long format.

Do I need to convert my time series into a DataFrame as well? If so, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A closer look at the documentation made me realize that omitting the `x` and `y` argument altogether leads to the `data` argument being interpreted in wide-form:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


samples = np.random.randn(20, 10)
ax = sns.violinplot(data=samples)
plt.show()
```

[image: Violin plot over time]

Answer (score 1):

In the violin plot documentation it says that the input x and y parameters do not have to be a data frame, but they have a restriction of having the same dimension. In addition, the variable y that you created has 10 rows and 200 columns. This is detrimental when plotting the graphics and causes a dimension problem.
I tested it and this code has no problems when reading the python file.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

time = np.arange(0, 200)
samples = np.random.randn(10, 200)

for sample in samples:
    ax = sns.violinplot(x=time, y=sample)
```

You can then group the resulting graphs using this link:
https://python-graph-gallery.com/199-matplotlib-style-sheets/

If you want to convert your data into data frames it is also possible. You just need to use pandas.

example

```
import pandas as pd
x = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```